# loss of leading zeros when using fast-xml-parser

Tags: node.js, fast-xml-parser

I am using fast-xml-parser and have a challenge in preserving leading zeros. I have simplified the example to the core of my problem.

I would like to preserve these leading zeros in the value of an item in the xmlOutput. I want xmlOutput to eventually equal xmlInput, so xmlOutput should be

```
 <item>08</item> instead of <item>8</item> which is what I get now.
```

**How can I configure that?**

Run the code beneath as follows: **node xmlparse**

```
const { XMLParser, XMLBuilder, XMLValidator } = require("fast-xml-parser");

const options = {
    parseTrueNumberOnly: true  //if true then values like "+123", or "0123" will not be parsed as number.
};

const xmlInput = '<item>08</item>';
console.log(xmlInput);  

const parser = new XMLParser(options);
let jsonData = parser.parse(xmlInput);
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

const builder = new XMLBuilder();
const xmlOutput = builder.build(jsonData,options)
console.log(xmlOutput);
```

I expected <item>08</item> but I got <item>8</item>

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the numbers with leading zero with double quote? `"`

Comment: no that's not an option because I get that 08 in from external messages and this value should really stay that way.

Comment: So I don't think that's possible then. Either you need to change parseTrueNumberOnly flag to false, or use another function wraps the numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: If you don't want to lose leading zeros in strings, don't parse them as numbers. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const options = {
  parseTrueNumberOnly : true,
};

let xml = `<root><value>0123</value></root>`;
let res = fastXmlParser.parse(xml, options);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = 
      {
        "alwaysCreateTextNode": false,
        "attributeNamePrefix": "@_",
        "attributesGroupName": false,
        "textNodeName": "#text",
        "ignoreAttributes": true,
        "removeNSPrefix": true,
        "parseNodeValue": true,
        "parseAttributeValue": false,
        "allowBooleanAttributes": false,
        "trimValues": true,
        "cdataTagName": "#cdata",
        "preserveOrder": false,
        "numberParseOptions": {
            "hex": false,
            "leadingZeros": false
        }
    }
  
    //OPTION
   
    const parser = new XMLParser(options);
    let jObj = parser.parse(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

```
const { XMLParser } = require('fast-xml-parser');
let data = `<Item>008</Item>`
const options = {
"numberParseOptions": {
    leadingZeros: false
}
};
const parser = new XMLParser(options);
const jObj = parser.parse(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(jObj));
```

Comment: Should spend some time explaining your answer instead of dumping code.